# Weblogic 12c - Connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: weblogic12c

can someone please help me resolve the following exception,

```
<Feb 10, 2015 11:43:47 AM CST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019> <[ServletContext@1297842065[app:_auto_generated_ear_ module:dmportal path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an IOException.

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote Host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Feb 10, 2015 11:43:50 AM CST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1297842065[app:_auto_generated_ear_ module:dmportal path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletNestedRuntimeException: Cannot parse POST parameters of request: '/dmportal/pushTime.do'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.mergePostParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:2426)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.parseQueryParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:2243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.peekParameter(ServletRequestImpl.java:2462)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.peekPostParameter(ServletRequestImpl.java:2445)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.access$2600(ServletRequestImpl.java:2014)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.net.ProtocolException: EOF after reading only: '0' of: '16' promised bytes, out of which at least: '0' were already buffered
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream.complain(PostInputStream.java:84)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream.read(PostInputStream.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl$1.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:251)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.mergePostParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:2400)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Feb 10, 2015 11:43:50 AM CST> <Error> <Kernel> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion violated.
java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion violated
    at weblogic.utils.Debug.assertion(Debug.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.mergePostParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:2404)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.parseQueryParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:2243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.peekParameter(ServletRequestImpl.java:2462)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$RequestParameters.peekPostParameter(ServletRequestImpl.java:2445)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am using Oracle OEPE eclipse with weblogic 12c. It was working fine before i started working on the Mobile application.

i have installed following plugins in my eclipse.
1. Android Tools
2. JBoos Hybrid Mobile tools

The following open source installed on my pc
1. Node Js
2. Cordova
3. Ripple emulator

Comment: Have you looked at https://community.oracle.com/message/10984135 or https://community.oracle.com/message/10984135 ? Could be a post timeout although it seems weird for such a tiny message

Comment: Yes I did and increased the post time out and it did not resolve the issue. This issue occurs with all type of  browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enabled SSL in weblogic and tried with https url and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url in config.xml file. then it will works.